# Difference between .archive and .xcarchive xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I noticed these two different file types, and I'm curious what is the difference between them.

If anyone knows it, I would really appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **archive file** is not really a file,its bundle of files and its metadata.
  **xcarchive** is a application **archive file** created by Xcode.It
 contains your app,its resources and dsym files.